# How to store a computed array of values as a constant

Tags: php

I have an array $stuff which is populated by a while loop from a mysql query in my initialisation script. I have php 5.6 but both of these fail:

```
define("STUFF", $stuff);
const STUFF = $stuff;
```

If I explicitly type out stuff as:

```
const STUFF = array(234243,44,222,66321);
```

Then that works. But I can't do that because I need to calculate the contents of the stuff array first (but it's constant for the rest of the subsequent scripts).

Comment: `define("STUFF", array());` allowed since php7.0

Comment: So just use a variable.

Comment: What kind of data stored in $stuff ? Logically, it "smells" bad to store dynamic data in constant. 
If you need something global you can store it in global variable, which is not so 'good practice'. Better to manage Config class that will store global configuration data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supposed to work in php 5.X (and you will likely not be able to access these values even if the statement is not rejected by the PHP engine) :

```
const STUFF = array(234243,44,222,66321);
```

constant values, whether regular or class constants, need to be of scalar type (i.e. not arrays, nor objects). PHP 5.6 introduced the possibility to declare array constants, however these can not be dynamically filled.

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php